# Averaging Matlab matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

In the Matlab programs I use I often have to average within a matrix (interpolation). The most straightforward way is to add the matrix and a shifted one (avg). However you could do the same operation using matrix multiplication (avg2). I noticed a considerable speed increase in the case of using matrix multiplication in the case of large matrices.

Could anyone explain why Matlab is able to process this multiplication faster than adding the same matrix? Also what are the possible downsides of using avg2() in respect to avg()?

Difference in runtime was a factor ~6 for this case (n=500).

```
function [] = speed()
%Speed test for averaging a matrix
n = 500;
A = rand(n,n);
tic
for i=1:100
    avg(A);
end
toc

tic
for i=1:100
    avg2(A);
end
toc

end

function B = avg(A,k)
if nargin<2, k = 1; end
if size(A,1)==1, A = A'; end
if k<2, B = (A(2:end,:)+A(1:end-1,:))/2; else B = avg(A,k-1); end
if size(A,2)==1, B = B'; end
end

function B = avg2(A,k)
if nargin<2, k = 1; end
if size(A,1)==1, A = A'; end
if k<2,
   m = size(A,1);
   e = ones(m,1);
   S = spdiags(e*[1 1],-1:0,m,m-1)'/2;
   B = S*A; else B = avg2(A,k-1); end
if size(A,2)==1, B = B'; end
end
```

Comment: Is `interp2` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Im afraid I cant give you an answer to the inner workings of the functions you are using. However, as they seem overly complicated, I felt I should make you aware of an easier (and a bit faster) way of doing this averaging.

You can instead use conv2 with a kernel of [0.5;0.5]. I have extended your code below:

```
function [A, T1, T2 T3] = speed()
%Speed test for averaging a matrix
n = 900;
A = rand(n,n);
tic
for i=1:100
    T1 = avg(A);
end
toc

tic
for i=1:100
 T2 = avg2(A);
end
toc

tic
for i=1:100
   T3 = conv2(A,[1;1]/2,'valid'); 
end
toc

if sum(sum(abs(T3-T2))) > 0
    warning('Method 3 not equal the other methods')
end
end

function B = avg(A,k)
if nargin<2, k = 1; end
if size(A,1)==1, A = A'; end
if k<2, B = (A(2:end,:)+A(1:end-1,:))/2; else B = avg(A,k-1); end
if size(A,2)==1, B = B'; end
end

function B = avg2(A,k)
if nargin<2, k = 1; end
if size(A,1)==1, A = A'; end
if k<2,
   m = size(A,1);
   e = ones(m,1);
   S = spdiags(e*[1 1],-1:0,m,m-1)'/2;
   B = S*A; else B = avg2(A,k-1); end
if size(A,2)==1, B = B'; end
end
```

Results:

Elapsed time is 10.201399 seconds.

Elapsed time is 1.088003 seconds.

Elapsed time is 1.040471 seconds.

Apologies if you already knew this.

Comment: I didn't know that function, thanks alot! It's seems to have the best of both worlds, same speed for large matrices as avg2 and also a fast speed for small matrices.